# My probability results are over 1. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: probability

Suppose you toss a coin four times.

The sample space
$$\Omega = \{HHHH, HHHT, HHT H, . . . , T T T T \}$$

contains $16$ outcomes and you should assume each outcome is equally likely.

Let $X$ be the *Binomial random*
variable that corresponds to the number of heads in an outcome,

*e.g., $X(HT HT) = 2$.*

Let $Y$ be the *Bernoulli
random variable* that evaluates to 1 if there is an even number of heads in the outcome,

*e.g., $Y (HHHT) = 0$
and $Y (HT HT) = 1$.*

Let $Z = X + Y$

$$ e.g., Z(HT HT) = X(HT HT) + Y (HT HT) = 2 + 1 = 3.$$ What are the
values of

$$P(Z = 0) , P(Z = 1) , P(Z = 3) , P(Z = 4) , P(Z = 5) , E(Z) ,var(Z) $$

I am not sure whether I am doing this correctly or not, because some of the results go over 1.

for example:

$$P(Z = 2) = P(X=1) + P(Y=1) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac {15}{16} = 1.18 $$

How am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

Comment: How can we have $Z=2$? Maybe $X=2$ and $Y=0$. But no, that is impossible, for if $X=2$ then $Y=1$. Maybe $X=1$ and $Y=1$. No, that's impossible, for if we have $1$ head, then the number of heads is odd. Maybe $X=0$ and $Y=2$. That too is impossible, since $Y$ cannot ever be $2$. Thus $\Pr(Z=2)=0$.

Comment: The formula you use to compute $\mathbb{P}\{Z=2\}$ is wrong, probabilities are not additive: $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \neq \mathbb{P}(A)+ \mathbb{P}(B)$ in general.

Comment: @Clement C. Then what's the formula I should use?

Comment: You could use $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$, or use a completely different manner (e.g., inspection, as @AndréNicolas suggests).

Comment: Oh I see. got it. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your statement that $P(Z=2)=P(X=1)+P(Y=1)$. Probability is not additive. For example, if $X'$ were the constant random variable $X'=0$, then $P(X'+X'=0)\neq P(X'=0)+P(X'=0)$, for $P(X'+X'=0)=1$ and $P(X'=0)+P(X'=0)=1+1=2$.

To compute the probability of $Z=2$, sum the probabilities of all possible events $E$ for which $Z(E)=2$. Since $Z=X+Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ take on non-negative integer values, we have
$$
P(Z=2)=P(X=0\text{ and }Y=2)+P(X=1\text{ and }Y=1)+P(X=2\text{ and }Y=0).
$$
Note that $Y$ only takes on the values $0$ and $1$, so the first term $P(X=0\text{ and }Y=2)$ vanishes. If $X(E)=1$ for some event $E$, then $E$ contains exactly one heads. But $1$ is not even, so for such $E$ we have $Y(E)=0$. So, $P(X=1\text{ and }Y=1)$ vanishes. Finally, if $X(E)=2$ for some event $E$, then $E$ contains exactly two heads. So then $Y(E)=1$ since $2$ is even, and thus for such $E$ we certainly can't have $Y(E)=0$. Thus, $P(X=2\text{ and }Y=0)$ vanishes.

We conclude that $P(Z=2)=0+0+0=0$.

One should be careful when carrying out the analysis above. It might be tempting to write $P(Z=2)=P(X=0)\cdot P(Y=2)+P(X=1)\cdot P(Y=1)+P(X=2)\cdot P(Y=0)$, but this is incorrect because the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.